A sinking feeling
Does adding water to an object that is in water make it sink.... or is it the lack of air in the object that makes it sink?
If I had a hollow sphere that as a whole floated on water. I divided that sphere into three distinct compartments that were air tight. I left two compartments alone and sealed full of air. If I filled one compartment with water then sealed the hole and this made the whole sphere sink.... if I could open the compartment filled with water at the bottom and the top of the compartment so the water was free to flow out and not 'trapped' would the sphere and the empty parts of the compartment that was flooded, now float?
Or in order to make this object float I have to replace the fluid in the flooded compartment with air? This image below, if the sand was replaced with water would the same thing happen?


It would have probably taken a lot less effort to just google "buoyancy" and clicking on the Wikipedia entry than making this post.

Thank you paulina. This is a really helpful suggestion. I appreciate you.

assuming the container has zero weight, then it will go down such that the water levels inside and outside are the same

Thank you Pato. I am wondering if water entering a sealed object adds to the weight of the object such that it causes the object to have "too much weight" and starts to sink.

if the container is full of water, it will remain just below the surface. Now if the density of the container's material is denser than water, it will sink,  it is less dense, it will tend to float, and if it the same, it can remain stable  at any depth. But the key is that, assuming  minimal containing weight compared to the amount of water inside it, it will sink to keep the water levels inside and outside the same. Now if you add the weight of the container, it depends on the density of the material.

It seems that the density of the object is the deciding factor as well as the force pushing down v the force pushing up. I want to see if you can sink a sealed object ( water in it ) then raise it by opening the seal and letting two parts that are less dense than water rise to the top. Seems you cant unless you can a)change the density of the object relative to the water/ liquid it has sunk in, b) actually remove water from the sunken object and replace that water with air .... I think.
